# How do I show a result from Random in a textview?

Tags: java, android

Consider:

```
import java.util.Random;

Random rand = new Random();

int n = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
```

This is Java code that picks a random number between 1 and 50.

I need to see what it picks in a textview!!

Comment: Do you want to show this randomly generated value in a TextView?  If so, something like textView.setText(Integer.toString(n)) will do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a  TextView to display the result.

Step 1. Adding ID to TextView, in the XML file.

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        .... />
```

Step 2. Finding TextView using ID, under onCreate method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myId);
    }
```

Step 3. Set the text with setText()

```
myTextView.setText(n+" "); //setText only accepts a String
```